# Hierarchical ToDoList as Adjacency List

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm building a todo list with a hierarchical structure , and I was searching for a good logic for it and found out that it is with Adjacency List.

The Goal is to be able to do a to-do list with hierarchical tasks (one task is the root, and then can have nodes, the nodes can have their own nodes and so on..)
So I built a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Owner] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Parent] [int] NULL,
```

after inserting data the table looks like this:

[image]

And I want a query that shows me all the roots, and if some root has nodes, so show it as well

my query is

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(tr.Parent) as SubCount
FROM Tasks t
INNER JOIN Tasks tr on t.Id = tr.Parent
GROUP BY t.Name, t.Owner, t.Id, t.Parent
UNION
SELECT t.*, 0 as SubCount
FROM Tasks t
where Parent IS NULL;
```

but the result is:

[image]

expected result should show only the rows with Parent IS NULL and the rows that have sub nodes, for example:

[image]

What should be the right query here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT
    T.Id,
    T.Name,
    T.Owner,
    T.Parent,
    (SELECT COUNT(IT.Id) FROM Tasks IT WHERE IT.Parent = T.Id) AS SubCount
FROM
    Tasks T
WHERE
    T.Parent IS NULL
```

Comment: yep works great :) thanks @Hebele (just I changed the COUNT(1) to COUNT(Id) to give me a more accurate answer)

Answer (score 0):

just Try this.,

```
select id, name , owner, parent,sum(SubCount) SubCount
from(
SELECT t.*, COUNT(tr.Parent) as SubCount
FROM Tasks t
INNER JOIN Tasks tr on t.Id = tr.Parent
GROUP BY t.Name, t.Owner, t.Id, t.Parent
UNION
SELECT t.*, 0 as SubCount
FROM Tasks t
where Parent IS NULL;
)d
group by id, name , owner, parent
```

Comment: This query gives me also the row where the parent is not null.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I just do it for the above data only.